# MySQL / C# Commit DataGridView Changes on cell edit?

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I have a Form with 5 dataGridViews, and I need to be able to save the changes to the Views when you click into a cell, similar to how you would work in Excel.

Here is my connection info:

`public static MySqlConnection db = new MySqlConnection();
public string jobnumber = "";
public string str = "SERVER=192.168.1.149; DATABASE=starflitesystems; UID=iuapp; " +
    "Password=iuapp";`

My Form Open Code:

```
public frmPricingTemplate_Start(string s)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    createTempTable();

    setDGVQueries();

    hidePanels(pnlBasePackage);
    btnReset(btnBasePackage);

    this.WindowState                = FormWindowState.Maximized;

    jobnumber                       = s;
    txtJobNumber.Text               = s;
    comboBox1.Visible               = false;
    comboBox2.Visible               = false;
    dataGridRefresh();

    dg2.AutoSizeColumnsMode         = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
    dg3.AutoSizeColumnsMode         = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
    dg4.AutoSizeColumnsMode         = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
    dg5.AutoSizeColumnsMode         = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
}
```

My Database Queries:

```
public void setDGVQueries()
{
    /* Strings for dataGridViews */
    selectDGV1 = "SELECT `Group`, Material, `Sub-Material` " +
                                            "FROM temporary_table " +
                                            "WHERE tab='" + activeTab + "';";

    selectDGV2 = "SELECT Quantity as `Quantity`, Cost as `Cost` " +
                                            "FROM temporary_table " +
                                            "WHERE tab='" + activeTab + "';";

    selectDGV3 = "SELECT Quantity2 as `Quantity`, Cost2 as `Cost` " +
                                            "FROM temporary_table " +
                                            "WHERE tab='" + activeTab + "';";

    selectDGV4 = "SELECT Quantity3 as `Quantity`, Cost3 as `Cost` " +
                                            "FROM temporary_table " +
                                            "WHERE tab='" + activeTab + "';";

    selectDGV5 = "SELECT Quantity as `Quantity`, Cost as `Cost` " +
                                            "FROM temporary_table " +
                                            "WHERE tab='" + activeTab + "';";
}
```

My Database Refresh Function:

```
public void dataGridRefresh()
{
    /* Define all dataTables for the dataGridViews */
    MySqlDataAdapter return1 = new MySqlDataAdapter(selectDGV1, str);
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable("base");
    return1.Fill(dt1);

    MySqlDataAdapter return2 = new MySqlDataAdapter(selectDGV2, str);
    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable("base");
    return2.Fill(dt2);

    MySqlDataAdapter return3 = new MySqlDataAdapter(selectDGV3, str);
    DataTable dt3 = new DataTable("base");
    return3.Fill(dt3);

    MySqlDataAdapter return4 = new MySqlDataAdapter(selectDGV4, str);
    DataTable dt4 = new DataTable("base");
    return4.Fill(dt4);

    MySqlDataAdapter return5 = new MySqlDataAdapter(selectDGV5, str);
    DataTable dt5 = new DataTable("base");
    return5.Fill(dt5);

    /* Set DataSources for all datagridViews */
    dg1.DataSource = dt1;
    dg2.DataSource = dt2;
    dg3.DataSource = dt3;
    dg4.DataSource = dt4;
    dg5.DataSource = dt5;
}
```

Basically, this loads certain information into my dataGridViews, but now, after that data is loaded, I need to be able to click into a cell, edit it, and have it automatically commit that change to the table once the focus leaves the cell.

I looked up a few things online about it, but they all appear to have used a different method to connect to the db, so I don't think they will work for me.

My theory is that I need to use a `for each (row r in dg1.SelectedRows){} Block, but I am unsure of exactly what to do.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since you are querying from the same table, temporary_table, why don't you try and do it all in one DataGridView?

Comment: Project Manager's decision, not mine. But that isn't the issue. I can easily write a few lines to refresh the other dataGridViews. The issue is the code to update the underlying table when the cell loses focus.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DataGridView.CellEnd
Edit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Event like this:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
         myDataDridView.CellEndEdit += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(myDataDridView_CellEndEdit);
    }
```

and then:

```
private void myDataDridView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
         try
         {
              // Your update query here
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
              MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
         }
    }
```

Comment: But what is the update query for this? That is my whole question. I can access the events fine.